# JQuery when child selection is found apply changes to each child

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have an HTML form `<select>` with a set of `<option>s`.

I want to have a separate search query that limits the number of options to those that match the search values if the value is not empty.

I have found lots of *almost* JQuery things to do this, but they're all either too simple or too precise or otherwise unsuitable.

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searcher').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
      var searcher = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

      $("#pcdupes select option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase() !== ':contains(searcher)';
      }).each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });

    } else {
      $("#pcdupes").show().children().show();

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='searcher'>
<BR>
<BR>
<div class="infobox" id="pcdupes">
  <select name='choices' size='22'>
    <option id='1'>horses</option>
    <option id='2'>cows</option>
    <option id='3'>sheeps</option>
    <option id='4'>goats</option>
    <option id='5'>blind paruvian monster bats</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I need the jquery to :

- On change of input field;

  - if not empty then do a case insensitive comparison to all text values in options.
  - only the container div is `#id` referenced, not the child `<select>` or it's children
  - Only the `<options>` that match the text **in part** are displayed.

    - For example; `<option id='1'>horses</option>` would match text value "hors";

I have looked up various things to build this system and have found out how to get the list of correct children but then can't find a working way to apply a change to each child. I currently get no console errors but I also get no results at all; select is empty.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `return $(this).val().toLowerCase() !== ':not:contains(searcher)';`

Comment: It should return the child to the filter list if the child's value (the `option`) is equal to the text searched for `searcher`. Looking at it, I suspect I may be searching the `id` values by mistake.... let me update that

Comment: `':not:contains(searcher)'` looks like a wishful selector string. Like `$("option:not:contains("+searcher+")")` - ditto `':contains(searcher)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#searcher').on('input', function() {
    const val = this.value;
    const $options = $("#pcdupes select option"); // store collection in variable
    if (val != '') {
      const searcher = val.toLowerCase();
      $options     // this is just a variable name usedabove to store collection
        .hide()
        .filter(function() {
          return this.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searcher) != -1;
        })
        .show();
    } else {
      $options.show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='searcher' autocomplete="off" />
<BR>
<BR>
<div class="infobox" id="pcdupes">
  <select name='choices' size='22'>
    <option id='1'>horses</option>
    <option id='2'>cows</option>
    <option id='3'>sheeps</option>
    <option id='4'>goats</option>
    <option id='5'>blind paruvian monster bats</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. I'm not familiar with the `$options` syntax. Is it just a shorthand variable ?

Comment: It is caching the options so I only access them once. I use $ prefix to remind me it is a jQuery object

Comment: I could call it $myOptions to not confuse

Comment: so the JQuery itself doesn't need the `$` or it uses it like a `var` reference?

Comment: No - I could call it myJQueryReferenceToOptionsCollection by instead chose $options - underscore is also allowed prefix